# What Happens if One Couples two Thermal Harmonic Oscillators at Different Temperatures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, harmonic-oscillator

Consider two identical initially uncoupled harmonic oscillators with Hamiltonians

$$\hat{H} = \frac{p_1^2}{2m}++\frac{m\omega^2x_1^2}{2},$$

$$\hat{H}_2 = \frac{p_2^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2x_2^2}{2}.$$

The Hamiltonian of the full system is then:

$$\hat{H} = H_1 + H_2$$

Each oscillator starts at a thermal state
$$\rho_1 = e^{-\beta_1 H_1},$$
$$\rho_2 = e^{-\beta_2 H_2}.$$
The full state $\rho = \rho_1\otimes\rho_2$ is stationary with respect to the evolution generated by $H$.

After some time, we switch an interaction, such that the full Hamiltonian of the system is given by

$$H_I = H_1 +H_2 + \lambda^2 x_1 x_2.$$

The question is: What will happen to the state $\rho$? I don't think it will thermalize to a temperature $\beta$ because that would either violate energy or entropy conservation. However, there are different options for what might happen to the state, such as:

1. Each of the oscillators ends up in a thermal state after tracing the other one, but it is a highly entangled state.
2. The state of the system keeps oscillating temperatures, without tending to any final state.

Which one of these is more accurate? Or, is there another possibility I haven't thought of?

Comment: "because that would either violate energy or entropy conservation" why exactly do you think this? What do you mean by entropy conservation? Are either or both of these systems coupled to anything external, such as a heat bath? Is there any dissipation in the system

Comment: Why do you think $\rho$ would not thermalize? Just curious if you could elaborate on that (how it would violate energy or entropy conservation). We can calculate the $C_v$ for each of the QHO at their respective temperatures. And then calculate the heat exchanged $C_v(T-T')$, (sum them and equate to 0 and find the final temp $T'$??

Comment: What I mean by entropy conservation: This is an isolated system, and time evolution is unitary. Unitary processes preserve entropy.

Answer (score 1):

Energy will spontaneously flow from the hotter system to the colder system, until the entire combined system reaches equilibrium at some new temperature. The total energy of the system will be conserved. The entropy will increase.

---

Entropy is constant for *adiabatic* processes in quantum mechanics. As discussed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_thermodynamics#Quantum_and_thermodynamic_adiabatic_conditions_and_quantum_friction), a necessary condition for adiabaticity is that the Hamiltonian must commute with itself at different times, $[H(t), H(t')] = 0$ for all $t, t'$.

We can check that this condition is violated for your case. Let $t$ be a time when $\lambda=0$, and let $t'$ be a time when $\lambda\neq 0$. Then (setting $\hbar=1$ so $[x, p] = i$)
\begin{eqnarray}
[H(t), H(t')] &=& \left[H_1 + H_2, H_1 + H_2 + \lambda x_1 x_2 \right] \\
&=& \lambda \left( [H_1, x_1] x_2 + x_1 [H_2, x_2] \right) \\
&=& \frac{- i \lambda}{m} \left( p_1 x_2 + x_1 p_2 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
So there is no reason to expect the entropy to remain constant in this scenario, unless the way the interaction is turned on is done very carefully (https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0709).

An important subtlety mentioned on the wikipedia page is that there is a distinction between the "energy entropy" and the "von Neumann entropy". The von Neumann entropy is conserved under unitary time evolution, but the energy entropy is not, and the latter is what is analogous to the thermodynamic entropy away from equilibrium (in equilibrium these two definitions of entropy agree). This is fleshed out in more detail in this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.2862. Section III.A describes an example that is conceptually very similar to yours, but even simpler: a gas is confined to one side of a box by a divider, which is then remove.

Comment: How can entropy increase if time evolution is a unitary process?

Comment: @Rick I added a bit more to the answer. Note the argument implicit in your question that entropy must always be conserved in quantum mechanics would imply a contradiction between quantum mechanics and thermodynamics.

Comment: Also note that I'm assuming here we are discussing the "energy entropy" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_thermodynamics#Entropy), which is the most relevant quantity for thermodynaimics. This is only equal to the [von Neumann entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy) in equilibrium.

Comment: You can recover the notions of classical thermodynamics once you consider an external system and trace over its degrees of freedom. This results in a non-unitary time evolution in the subsystem that produces mixedness. It can also create time dependencies on the effective Hamiltonian for subsystems, which would be the case you handle in your answer.

Comment: Regarding your proof that the Hamiltonian does not commute with itself at different times, the initial Hamiltonian of the system is completely irrelevant in this case. I could simply initiate the system that has a Hamiltonian given by $H_1 + H_2 + \lambda^2 x_1x_2$ at all times. The reason I talked about the initial Hamiltonian was to give a physical interpretation for the states $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$. This invalidates the "no entropy conservation" you presented.

Comment: @Rick I guess I can't help you, sorry about that. I think you must be missing a piece in the way you describe your example, there must be some tracing over a heat bath or something that accounts for the change in entropy. But from the point of view of thermodynamics (which quantum mechanics respects), it's pretty clear that the entropy has to increase as energy flows from the hot system to the cold system in the form of heat.